# How to replace getSavePassword() in API level19

Tags: android

As mentioned in Android documentation, the method getSavePassword() was deprecated on API level 18.
I use this method on a android custom application (Android version 4.3 and lower) to save user credentials in webview but this feature does not work on Android version 4.4 since it was deprecated.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#getSavePassword()
How can I replace this method to keep the feature (save credentials in Android 4.4 and higher)?

Regards

Comment: I doubt you can unless you implement a custom JavaScript interface, because as stated: "Saving passwords in WebView will not be supported in future versions."